# How to set WS-SecurityPolicy in an inbound CXF service in Mule?

Tags: cxf, ws-security, mule

When configuring the service for handling UsernameToken and signatures, it's setup like this:

```
<service name="serviceName">
  <inbound>
    <cxf:inbound-endpoint address="someUrl" protocolConnector="httpsConnector" >
      <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
        <spring:constructor-arg>
          <spring:map>
            <spring:entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp Signature" />
            <spring:entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="serverCallback" />
            <spring:entry key="signaturePropFile" value="wssecurity.properties" />
          </spring:map>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
        </spring:bean>
      </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:inbound-endpoint>
  </inbound>
</service>
```

But how is it possible to create a policy of what algorithms that are allowed, and what parts of the message that should be signed?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to ask the Mule folks.  Last I checked, they hadn't moved to CXF 2.2.x yet.   If they ARE on 2.2.x, you could use the WS-SecPol support built into CXF.

Comment: I think they've moved to CXF 2.2.x. But reading the description at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html doesn't explain much how this is done.

Although it does state that "WS-SecurityPolicy support is ONLY available for "WSDL first" scenarios". So I guess you have to manually define the security policy in the WSDL file, and then it's automatically applied as you use CXF to create the web service from that file.